backdrop-filter blur not working when combined with mix-blend-mode
I'm trying to create a flex layout where each of the flex items "cut through" the flex box, revealing the image that's beneath the flex box. I've managed to achieve this by using mix-blend-mode property.
However, I also want the flex items to have a backdrop-filter: blur, so that the background they reveal is blurry only for those flex items.
The following snippet illustrates what I'm trying to achieve, however the backdrop-filter does not seem to work.
How can I update this snippet to achieve the desired effect?


body {
  margin: 0
}
.background {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Fesoj_-_Papilio_machaon_%28by%29.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  
  /* Used to make the flex items "cut through" the flex box */
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Ased to make the flex items "cut through" the flex box */
  background-color: grey;
  
  /* *** This doesnt seem to work *** */
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}
<div class="background">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>



Edit
I've been able to achieve something similar by not having the flex items "cut through" the flex box, but rather use a transparent flex box and add extra elements above and below the flex box, and extra flex items serving as the gap/separators. It's not ideal since it makes applying a border-radius to the flex items almost impossible, but it does the job.


body {
  margin: 0
}
.background {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Fesoj_-_Papilio_machaon_%28by%29.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.horizontal {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.separator {
  flex: 0 0 20px;
  background-color: black;
}
<div class="background">
  <div class='horizontal'></div>
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="box separator"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box separator"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box separator"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box separator"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box separator"></div>
    </div>
  <div class='horizontal'></div>
</div>




No mix-blend-mode required. Make .flex transparent, and fill the gaps with box-shadow on .box. Less and simpler code:


body {
  margin: 0
}
.background {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Fesoj_-_Papilio_machaon_%28by%29.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 20px #000;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}
<div class="background">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>






body {
            margin: 0
        }
        .background {
            background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Fesoj_-_Papilio_machaon_%28by%29.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
        }   
        .layer{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
            backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .flex {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            gap: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: black;
            
            /* Used to make the flex items "cut through" the flex box */
            mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
        }
        .box {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            /* Ased to make the flex items "cut through" the flex box */
            background-color: grey;
            
            /* *** This doesnt seem to work *** */
        }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background">
        <div class="layer">
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




Thanks for your answer, however unfortunately it does not work. Please add a description to your answer to explain your solution and why it works (although in this case it doesnt work).
